# Не отоброжается php запрос

Tags: php, sql

Здраствуйте , помогите в одном вопросе.

```
    <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , 'root' , 'test_db');
  if($connection == false){
    echo "cant connect to sql";
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM `articles_categories`");
  ?>
  <ul>
  <?php
    while(($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))){
      echo  '<li>' . $cat['title'] .'</li>';
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Вместо списка с категориями ,  у меня выводит 4 точки , спасибо заранее.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте структуру таблицы articles_categories в  вопрос

Comment: Спасибо помоголо.

Comment: закрывайте вопрос